# Evaluate cron expression

Tags: bash, cron

Is there a command line tool that will simply evaluate a cron expression and return a bool response if it is supposed to be running right now? I'm looking for something I can use as a utility in another bash script. Something like so:

```
run_script=$(/tools/evaluate-cron-expression "02 4 * * *")
if [ "$run_script" -eq "1" ] # etc etc
```

I know, I know, I could just setup a real cron job, but I'm playing with the idea of wrapping all of my scheduled scripts inside of another script.

Comment: This is actually very cool and I could make it work, except my production servers are limited to PHP 5.2 :( https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression

Comment: What is the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to pass a cron expression to a script and, given the current time, determine whether or not it is a match.

Comment: I guess that is pretty specific, but again why?  What more general problem are you trying to solve that would lead you to a solution like this?

Comment: I want to have a single generic function that runs every minute, evaluates an entire directory of scripts and one-by-one fires them off if the cron string matches. My team has accumulated dozens and dozens of scripts that are untracked and undocumented. We just want to get them all into a single place and under a single logging system. There have been too many recent occurrences of things that suddenly stop working because we either didn't know a cron existed or didn't know it had recently failed.

Comment: So you are basically duplicating the cron function?  Why not use the functionality contained there....like putting the cron entries into seperate files under /etc/cron.d?

Comment: I agree with mdpc. Use puppet to push out cron jobs, and / or use cron.d files. Otherwise you'll just be duplicating what cron actually is designed to do.

Comment: It's a mostly-duplicate of cron, except that it has all sorts of new opportunities for bugs and edge cases etc. For example, suppose we have a job scheduled for "02 4 * * *" and another for "03 4 * * *". If the first job takes more than 2 minutes to run, will the second job be: 1) skipped because the next test will be at minute 04, 2) deferred until the first job finishes, or 3) run at minute 03 because the first job was run in the background and didn't hold up the scheduler (in which case how do you handle output from multiple jobs running at once)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a Class that deals with this here: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/641-PHP-Compares-timestamps-with-crontab-style-specifiers.html

I've been using this Class for something like 7 years.  It has worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

python version from php idea, Thanks!

```
import datetime

VALID_RANGES = {
    'min': '0-59',
    'hour': '0-23',
    'day': '1-31',
    'mon': '1-12',
    'week': '0-6',
}


def is_cron_time(sc: str, time_now: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()) -> bool:

    cron_l = sc.split(' ')
    if not len(cron_l) == 5:
        return False

    cron_d = {
        'min': cron_l[0],
        'hour': cron_l[1],
        'day': cron_l[2],
        'mon': cron_l[3],
        'week': cron_l[4]
    }

    time_now_d = {
        'min': time_now.minute,
        'hour': time_now.hour,
        'day': time_now.day,
        'mon': time_now.month,
        'week': time_now.weekday()
    }

    for part, val in cron_d.items():
        if val == '*':
            continue
        values = []
        """For patters like 0-23/2"""
        if '/' in val:
            rng, steps = val.split('/')
            if rng == '*':
                rng = VALID_RANGES[part]
            start, stop = [int(s) for s in rng.split('-')]
            values = list(range(start, stop, int(steps)))
        else:
            """For patters like :
            2
            2,5,8
            2-23
            """
            for v in val.split(','):
                if v == '*':
                    # should never happen
                    break
                if '-' in v:
                    start, stop = [int(s) for s in v.split('-')]
                    values = list(range(int(start), int(stop)))
                else:
                    values.append(int(v))

        if time_now_d[part] not in values:
            return False
    return True


def test():
    DT = datetime.datetime
    _now = DT.now()
    tests = [
        {'cron': '* * * * *', 'dt': _now, 'ass': True},
        {'cron': '0 * * * *', 'dt': DT(_now.year, _now.month, _now.day, _now.hour, 0), 'ass': True},
        {'cron': '2 * * * *', 'dt': DT(_now.year, _now.month, _now.day, _now.hour, 10), 'ass': False},
        {'cron': '*/2 * * * *', 'dt': DT(_now.year, _now.month, _now.day, _now.hour, 10), 'ass': True},
        {'cron': '2-15 * * * *', 'dt': DT(_now.year, _now.month, _now.day, _now.hour, 10), 'ass': True},
    ]
    for cron, dt, ass in [t.values() for t in tests]:
        assert is_cron_time(cron, dt) is ass, f'{cron} fail on {dt}'


test()
```